# How to download MQL4 IDE and Editor?

Tags: metaprogramming, metatrader4

Dear all.
I am a newbie in MQL4 (Metaquotes Languages 4.0). I really want to download the IDE and programing tool for this languages but I can't. I can't download this since I can't find any download link.

If you know about this, please tell me.

Thanks a lot.

Binh Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetaTrader4Server and DDE can only be installed on brokers' server after they purchase the platform. I'm afraid it's not possible for individual traders to download and test. To code EA, first you need to open the terminal, then press F4 or go to Tools/ MetaQuotes Language Editor. Other relevant information about MQL4 language can be found on the website http://www.mql4.com.

Answer (score 5):

Metaquote has its own IDE for developing Indicators or Expert Advisor.

Just download the MT4 software from metaquotes website and click on tools>Metaquotes Language Editor

You can create Expert Advisor, script, Indicators or whatever you want with it if you have some previous programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

### A default IDE does not meet all flavours users may have for modern IDE

While some progress is visible, it is also true, that MQL4 code-base maintenance is not an easy task without a set of good IDE tools. Failing on that hurts and costs a lot of time/efforts in areas, that require rather non-creative work. That leads to a repetitive dilemma -- should I / can I change our corporate tool-chain for easing of the current headaches?

### Another IDE? Yes, possible.

MQL4 can be easily used with editors, which allow configurable **syntax-highlighting**, configurable compiler-settings ( `MetaLang.exe` ) and add some more features of your preference and choice like **auto-completion** or **parentheses-matching** might be for your style of work.

Practical positive experience has been done with these few, having both **`wXP`** and **`linux`** ports:

- Geany ( collapsable syntax-sections, vertical block operations )
- SciTe ( collapsable syntax-sections, with an MQL4 plugin )
- jEdit ( collapsable syntax-sections )

### What helps best depends on scale, version controls and re-use patterns

Having code-base with more than a few hundreds man*years, good and powerful tools are important. Both for productivity reasons and for version controls ( just remember MQL4-syntax-creep since Build 600+, not speaking about a "New"-MQL4.5678 ).

The team is using several different IDE-tools in parallel, due to strengths and weaknesses these have per incident.

So do not hesitate to use more than one IDE too.

[image: Source code with 10k+ SLOCs]